# How to prove that $T$ is not compact defined on $c_{00}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Define bounded operator $T: c_{00}\to c_{00}$ by for $x\in c_{00}$:
$$
T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=(x_1, \frac{x_2}{2}, \frac{x_3}{3},\dots, \frac{x_k}{k},\dots)
$$
How to prove that $T$ is not compact?

---

My idea is to prove it by contradiction: we choose a bounded sequence $\{x_k\}\in c_{00}$ and if $\{Tx_k\}$ does not have convergent subsequence, then $T$ is not compact.

If I choose $\{e_k\}$ with $k$-th coordinate one and others zero, then for any $m> n$:
$$
\|Te_{km}-Te_{kn}\|=\|\frac{1}{m}e_{km}-\frac{1}{n}e_{kn}\|=\frac{1}{n}?
$$

It seems that this bounded sequence converges? I am confused about that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the sequence $$x_n =(1, \dots, 1,0, 0, \dots)$$ with $n$ ones. This sequence is bounded. However, $(Tx_n)_n$ has no converging subsequence as $(1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots)$ is not in $c_{00}$.

We have $$Tx_n=(1,1/2, \dots, 1/n, 0, 0, \dots).$$ Suppose there exist a convergent subsequence and let $x$ be its limit. Note that $(Tx_n)^{(k)}=1/k$ for $n>k$. Thus, $x^{(k)}=1/k$. However,$(1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots)$ is not in $c_{00}$.

Comment: You can simply say that $Tx_n$ converges in the larger space $c_0$, and so every subsequence converges to the same limit. (which is not in $c_{00}$)

Comment: @Mark That's of course correct. Though it is from a technical point of view the same computation.

Answer (score 0):

The operator $T$ is an algebraic epimorphism of $c_{00}.$ Any such operator is not compact. Indeed let $\delta_n$ denote the standard basis of $c_{00}.$ There are $v_n\in c_{00}$ such that $Tv_n=\delta_n.$ The elements $$u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over 2^k\|v_k\|}v_k$$ belong to the unit ball and $$Tu_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over 2^k\|v_k\|}\delta_k$$
The sequence $Tu_n$ has no accumulation point in $c_{00}.$